# XSLT :: Select following segments until next tag

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have following input XML. The successive E_Records are optional and it should be populated into L_Record. I have written the below XSLT coding. Is there any changes should i have to do?

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Record>
      <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
     </L_Record>
     <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>3</E_Qty>
     </E_Record>
     <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>4</E_Qty>
     </E_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
     </L_Record>
  </Record>
  <Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
     </L_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
     </L_Record>
     <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>1</E_Qty>
     </E_Record>
     <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>2</E_Qty>
     </E_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
     </L_Record>
     <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>5</E_Qty>
     </E_Record>
     <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>6</E_Qty>
     </E_Record>
  </Record>
```

The Output XML i am expecting is

```
 <Record>
   <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
      <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>3</E_Qty>
      </E_Record>
      <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>4</E_Qty>
      </E_Record>
    </L_Record>
    <L_Record>
       <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
       <L_Level>2</L_Level>
    </L_Record>
  </Record>
  <Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
     </L_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>      
       <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>1</E_Qty>
       </E_Record>
       <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>2</E_Qty>
       </E_Record>
     </L_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>      
        <E_Record>
          <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
          <E_Qty>5</E_Qty>
        </E_Record>
        <E_Record>
          <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
          <E_Qty>6</E_Qty>
        </E_Record>
    </L_Record>
  </Record>
```

I have written the XSLT mapping for this as below but i am not getting the required output. Could you please help me on this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
         <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Record/L_Record">
   <L_Record>
    <xsl:variable name="header" select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:if test = "not(following-sibling::L_Record)">
            <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::E_Record[preceding-sibling::L_Record = $header]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
    </L_Record> 
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help me on this?
When i am executing the above code, Record 1 is working fine, but the record 2 is not working properly. The E-Record segment is not appearing in the L-Record segment.

Comment: See any example on `for-each-group group-starting-with` in your favourite XSLT 2 text book or introduction or the mini section https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info based on the spec samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that uses `group-starting-with` mentioned by Martin...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="L_Record">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node(),current-group()[self::E_Record]"/>          
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRApc

Comment: Hi Daniel,Thanks for the help!!! I got another issue while testing by adding extra segments which is in the same sequence H_Record, C_Record, L_Record, E_Record and R_Record , but those segments C_Record and R_Records are not appearing while executing the XSLT code. Could you please help?

Comment: @SrinivasBajina, ask a new question with the relevant details in the question, in particular with those changes in the input which output you then expect, i.e. where the other records are supposed to end up.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have modified the question as per the request

Comment: @SrinivasBajina, I would suggest to ask a new question, it doesn't make sense to receive an answer to then change the requirements.